# Running Nodejs application without listening on a port

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I have a Nodejs application hosted on Heroku. There's no `app.listen()` in the code. How does Heroku run the server while the code doesn't specify to start listening on a port ?

So, if there's no `app.listen` , is the connection between a client and our server persistent ? Or for each request coming from a client , we have one temporary connection which dies right after the server sends back the result ?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//app.use('/', routes);
//app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


//var portNumber = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var portNumber = process.env.PORT || 9091;

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
  console.log('Connection');
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.write('hellooooo');
  response.end();
});

server.listen(portNumber, function() {
  console.log('Server is listing on port : ' + portNumber);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Either it does't, or Heroku is smart enough to add one in for you.

Comment: Seeing your edit, yes that's likely what's happening.

Comment: Please show us your core server startup code so we can see what you are doing and can then answer the question appropriately.  HTTP connections are generally not persistent.  They are usually connected, data is transferred and then the connection is closed.  That is how a normal browser request works.

Comment: Added the code. I know HTTP is not persistent, but I meant if sessions are the same or not.

Comment: Is the app working as intended (all middleware and routes etc.)? `var portNumber = process.env.PORT || 9091;` is binding to the environment PORT set by Heroku and `server.listen()` is currently using this. However, you should either be using `app.listen()`, or passing `app` to the `server.listen()` call